# Why binding data does not work with union sql query in C#?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a `listbox` with a `union` query as `datasource` :

```
  public partial class FrmCodes : Form
     
{
    SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server = AMR-PC\SQLEXPRESS ; Database=PlanningDB ; Integrated Security = True");
    SqlDataAdapter da,da2;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    CurrencyManager Cm;
    SqlCommandBuilder Cmdb;
    string prm,SlctType;
      
    public FrmCodes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Code,Item,Type FROM Items UNION SELECT ProductCode,Product,Family FROM Products", Cn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        ListItems.DataSource = dv;
        ListItems.DisplayMember = "Item";
       
      
    }
```

I am trying to bind data to four textboxes I have in this form based on `listbox` choice , First i tried the union query directly but keep getting error " Column x doesn’t exist .... " So I used the original two queries seperated Like this :

```
  private void ListItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Slctd = (DataRowView)ListItems.SelectedItem;
            if (Slctd != null)
            {
                prm = Slctd["Code"].ToString();
                SlctType = Slctd["Type"].ToString();
                
              // Try to solve two bindings to the same property error 
                txtcode.DataBindings.Clear();
                txtItem.DataBindings.Clear();
                txtMaterialType.DataBindings.Clear();
                txtFamily.DataBindings.Clear();

                if (SlctType == "Material" || SlctType == "Master" || SlctType == "Packing" || SlctType == "Mix")
                {
                    
                    this.txtMaterialType.Visible = true;
                    this.lblMaterialType.Visible = true;
                    this.txtFamily.Visible = false;
                    this.lblFamily.Visible = false;
                    //this.PgBom.Hide();
                    try
                    {
                        da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Code,Item,Type FROM Items WHERE Code LIKE '%prm%' ", Cn);
                        da2.Fill(dt2);

                        txtcode.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "Code");
                        txtItem.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "Item");
                        txtMaterialType.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "Type");

                        Cm = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[dt2];
                    }
                    catch (SqlException Err)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This Error Occured :" + Err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // MessageBox.Show("You Chosed : " + prm + " It Is Product ", "Product");
                    this.txtFamily.Visible = true;
                    this.lblFamily.Visible = true;
                    this.txtMaterialType.Visible = false;
                    this.lblMaterialType.Visible = false;
                    try
                    {
                        da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductCode,Product,Family FROM Products WHERE ProductCode LIKE '%prm%'", Cn);
                        da2.Fill(dt2);
                        txtcode.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "ProductCode");
                        txtItem.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "Product");
                        txtFamily.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt2, "Family");

                        Cm = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[dt2];
                    }
                    catch (SqlException Err)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This Error Occured :" + Err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                    }

                }
            }

            else
            {
                prm = "";
            }

            }
```

But nothing happens with the textboxes no data appears in the textboxes .
If the data appeared I need to edit , add , delete using `Currency Manager` :

```
  private void CmdEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Cm.EndCurrentEdit();
                Cmdb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da2);
                da.Update(dt2);
                Cm.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("Edited Successfuly", "Done :)", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
               
            }

            catch (SqlException Err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Error Occured :" + Err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


            }
        }
```

Sorry for the long post , Thanks in advance .

**Edit #1 : When i tried to set the criteria of the sql query to fixed value it works fine and the edit of data works too .**

```
da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductCode,Product,Family FROM Products WHERE ProductCode LIKE '10001'", Cn);
```

But if the criteria is a variable value or `Textbox.Text` nothing shows in the textboxes.

**Edit #2 : I changed the referring syntax from  `LIKE '%prm%'` to `LIKE @prm` and added this code :**

```
 da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm", "%" + Slctd["Code"].ToString() + "%");
```

And it worked perfectly .

Comment: Reading should be fine but writing back to the DB won't work correctly for a UNION query

Comment: Thanks for reply, I seperated the UNION query in two queries as i mentioned but still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Net core or netfw project?

Comment: Netframework visual studii 2012

Comment: What does `LIKE '%prm%'` mean? You say in your edit you are trying a variable value. Is prm supposed to be a variable? As written this is just a literal string "prm".

Comment: prm is a variable not just string , I figured it out please have a look on Edit #2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching I figured it out , The problem was

```
da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Code,Item,Type FROM Items WHERE Code LIKE '%prm%' ", Cn);
```

I changed it to :

```
da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Code,Item,Type FROM Items WHERE Code LIKE @prm ", Cn);
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm", "%" + Slctd["Code"].ToString() + "%");
```

Works great now thanks everyone.